# Many To Many Field Multiple Users

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I'm slowly gaining my knowledge with Django, but this one has me stumped.  I am trying to create a form that multiple users need to approve.  In doing this, I have created a CreateView with a modelform and that works fine.  I have also created an UpdateView, and this works fine as well, with the caveat that if one user updates the model form, they are essentially updating it for everyone.  Through my research, I've determined that the users should actually be updating an INSTANCE of the form?  But I can seem to figure out how to do this.  Here is my code model.  I tried to exclude the parts the code that weren't essential to this problem.

My Model

```
class Book(models.Model):

    approver = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,related_name='approver')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.quiz_name
```

CreateView

```
class CreateBookView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):

    model = Book
    form_class = CreateBook
    template_name = 'Book/create_book.html'

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(CreateBookView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['user'] = self.request.user
        return kwargs

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save()
        self.object.checker.add()
        self.object.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('Test:book_test')
```

ModelForm

```
class CreateBook(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:

        model = Book
        fields = ('approver',) 

        def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CreateBook, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.fields['approver'] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
                                    widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
                                    queryset= User.objects.all())
```

UpdateView

```
class BookUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin,UpdateView):

    model = Book
    template_name = 'Test/book_update.html'
    form_class = ReviewNewBookForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('Test:book_menu')

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(BookUpdateView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['user'] = self.request.user
        return kwargs
```

ModelForm

```
class ReviewNewBookorm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ['approver',]

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ReviewNewBookForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['approver'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'choices3'
        self.fields['approver'].initial = " "
```

The code above all works perfectly, except I can't quite work out how to save a separate instance of the form for each approver who is selected.  One user can approver the form, and the form is instantly changed to approved.  What I'm trying to do is select multiple approvers, which totally works in CreateView, but when it comes to the UpdateView, I can't figure it out.  Any help or thoughts are appreciated.  I have tried to include the form_valid section that I have in CreateView on the UpdateView but it doesn't seem to matter.  I suspect I have to do something different in the form_valid for UpdateView but can't quite figure it out.  I found a similar question on SO, but it was solved using a function based view, I'm looking for a somewhat equivalent Class Based View for this issue, as my issue is not identical to this one, but it's close... [Django UpdateView - get initial data from many-to-many field and add them when saving form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46759003/django-updateview-get-initial-data-from-many-to-many-field-and-add-them-when-s?rq=1)